# Select all containing elements of a div

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

I would like to select all elements within a container e.g. a div. It shouldn't matter what kind of an element is within the container and it should be possible to select those elements without any classes assigned to them, to stay as flexible as possible. 
I want to build this quickly written "logo-ticker" as a jQuery Plugin:

http://apkunden.de/dev/index.html

The goal is to make it possible to use this with any html element, not just imgs. I know a very common way to accomplish this is via the use of a class assigned to any relevant element. But as it turns out I'm a lazy person and I don't want to assign all those classes :D.

Now I know there is the all selector ("*") in jQuery and I thought of doing something like this:

```
    $("#container").find("*");
```

But then on the jQuery API page there is a warning that the all selector is very slow. Question now is, if it makes sense at all to use the ("*") selector. If it has that much impact on performance I'd rather not be lazy...

Anyone with experience or advice with this?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the same [docs](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/) (emphasize mine):

> Caution: The all, or universal, selector is extremely slow, **except when used by itself**.

That sentence implies that`$(this).find('* > p')` is much slower than `$(this).find('*')`, so I think it's pretty safe to do that, and I honestly can't think of any better (as in efficient), since your requirements is to `get all elements`

EDIT:

As per my comment, from the `children()` docs:

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only
>   travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse
>   down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
>   etc.) as well.

Comment: Ok, thx. I will test it. Guess I will also compare performance against the .children() selector.

Comment: If you intend to only take the `direct` children of your container, then you can absolutely use `children()`, but if you need to get all the descendants of `container`, `children()` won't get you those

Comment: Yeah, I think .children() would better suit my needs. Thx, for your answer anyways, it made me understand the all selector better.

Comment: still curious about the performance... maybe I will test both against each other.

Comment: @TimG it's no-brainer that `children()` is faster than `find('*')`, just by looking at the resultset returned ;) see here for benchmark: http://jsperf.com/jaja-children-vs-find

Comment: Your absolutely right, thought of that too. Question is, if it would still be faster, if there were only direct children. Doesn't really matter because I will use children() anyway, but still... But now that I have the link to the tester (awesome tool btw!) I can play around myself. Thx again.

Answer (score 1):

From the JQuery Spec ([link](http://api.jquery.com/children/)):

> .children( [selector] )
>
> Description: Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

So in your case:

```
 $("#container").children();
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just use the

```
    $("#container").children()
```

method in jquery, are you wanting to loop through the results? Does it matter if the child elements also contain child elemetent?

As for speed, Id be surprised if using the all selector, is any slower than any other selector, as they are surely based on the number of results. (maybe wrong though)

Comment: The child elements should not have further child elements (or at least they should not be selected), so I guess this might even be safer then using ("*"). In the end I need the width of the child elements to add them all up to the total ticker width.